# Why does this function print the result, but return none?

Tags: python, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

```
def solve(sudoku):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10): 
                    if possible(x, y, n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        solve(sudoku)
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0
                        
                return
    print(np.matrix(sudoku))
    return sudoku
```

This function prints the solved Sudoku, however `print(solve(sudoku))` returns none. Why does the function return none if it can print(sudoku)?

Comment: Because that's what `return` without an argument does.

Comment: You'll need to `return solve` to pass the result back up the recursive call chain and finally return that result to the original caller. Otherwise, on the way back up, `return None` and/or `sudoku[y][x] = 0` will give you something other than the solved sudoku, either `None` or a sudoku zeroed out.

Comment: There is clearly a problem with your algorithm if you want to return a solved matrix, because the only time you ever insert a number into the solution, you *always* then set it back to 0. The resulting matrix can therefore never contain any digits other than 0.

Comment: Turns out the array was incrementally being set back to zero as it was beeing passed back up the recursive chain. I need to fill a completely new array with the solved sudoku at the time of the original print statement. Now it works just fine :)

Comment: @Henri Glad you worked it out. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solve(sudoku):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10): 
                    if possible(x, y, n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        solve(sudoku)
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0
                        
                return # this might be a problem
    print(np.matrix(sudoku))
    return sudoku
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions must be wrong.

If you are saying that `print(solve(sudoku))` print `None`, then this must be what is happening.

The only way for that to happen is if the last `return` is from the third line from the bottom of your code.